# Jenkins won't start after shutdown

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins

I shut down Jenkins from the console and then tried to start it using the following command:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/jenkins start
```

but instead got the following exception. How can I restore it again?

P.S. I'm running jenkins on ubuntu 16.04

```
     com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: 

    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:325)
    Caused: jenkins.util.xstream.CriticalXStreamException: hudson.security.ProjectMatrixAuthorizationStrategy : hudson.security.ProjectMatrixAuthorizationStrategy
    ---- Debugging information ----
    message             : hudson.security.ProjectMatrixAuthorizationStrategy
    cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
    cause-message       : hudson.security.ProjectMatrixAuthorizationStrategy
    class               : hudson.model.Hudson
    required-type       : hudson.model.Hudson
    converter-type      : hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter
    path                : /hudson/authorizationStrategy
    line number         : 12
    version             : not available
-------------------------------
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:354)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.unmarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:268)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:72)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:65)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:66)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:50)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:134)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:32)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1189)
    at hudson.util.XStream2.unmarshal(XStream2.java:161)
    at hudson.util.XStream2.unmarshal(XStream2.java:132)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:1173)
    at hudson.XmlFile.unmarshal(XmlFile.java:178)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Unable to read /var/lib/jenkins/config.xml
    at hudson.XmlFile.unmarshal(XmlFile.java:181)
    at hudson.XmlFile.unmarshal(XmlFile.java:161)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.loadConfig(Jenkins.java:3039)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.access$1200(Jenkins.java:309)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$13.run(Jenkins.java:3141)
Caused: hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:250)
```

Comment: does any have existed file in /var/lib/jenkins/config.xml ?

Comment: yes exists @ThanhNguyenVan

Comment: try to switch to `jenkins` user, then start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please switch to `su - jenkins` user then start jenkins.

Comment: try to run : `chmod 777 /var/lib/jenkins/config.xml`

Comment: Very strange. Still same error after running the above command and try to start again!

Comment: did you update jenkins, install plugins , or changed anything in `config.xml` file ?

Comment: In case this might help, I'm running the VM on Azure cloud

Comment: Last change was trying to SSH into the virtual machine and type  
 sudo visudo

to append 
jenkins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL to the file.